# Acer Aspire F5-573G: black screen, fan running - worked once after CMOS battery reset

Tags: laptop, bios, acer-aspire

I'm trying to fix a Acer Aspire F5-573G which suddenly stopped working. When pressing the power button, the fan runs for a moment, and then the system powers off.

I suspected the BIOS, so I removed the CMOS battery and put it back in after some time. With that, it actually started and booted into Windows, with everything working. I thought that fixed it, so I turned it off. However, when trying to turn it back on, it had the same problem as before. I tried to reset the BIOS two times again (which is tedious, because most of the laptop needs to be disassembled for access to the battery), but to no avail.

Does that mean it must have something to do with the BIOS? I'd assume so, as everything seems to have been working after the first BIOS reset. I noticed that as soon as it booted into Windows, an update was running, so maybe some Windows update messed up the BIOS in some way (not sure how this could happen, just a wild guess)? Is there anything I could try? My hope was to get it back running with a BIOS reset, and then update the BIOS with the .exe from Acer, but like I said, I can't seem to get there anymore.

Comment: 1. Can you get into BIOS, or does it shut down? If so, have you tried running from USB, e.g., Hirens CD or Ubuntu? 2. Have you checked the BIOS/clock cell?

Comment: 1. No, the screen stays completely black on startup, only the fan powers on for couple of seconds.
2. What do you mean by "BIOS/clock cell"? The CMOS cell battery gives the correct voltage, if that is what you're asking.

Comment: See if the RAM is properly seated, as well as all the connectors. If you can't even get into BIOS, it might be a simple hardware issue.

Comment: I dis- and reassembled most of the hardware components, with no success. Because everything was working once after the first BIOS reset, I assume all of the hardware components are working in some capacity.